# How to get turtle to STOP after 5 circles! Python 3.x

Tags: python

I need my turtle to stop after 4 circles but he won't do it! Can anyone help? I wouldn't ask unless I was really stuck and I have been researching for a while.

```
from turtle import *
import time
### Positioning
xpos= -250

ypos= -250

radius= 40

speed(10)

###Program main function
while radius == 40:
    pu()
    goto (xpos, ypos)
    pd()
    begin_fill()
    color("red")
    circle(radius)
    end_fill()
    xpos = xpos + (radius*2)
```

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following code would draw your N times, where you would replace N with the number of circles you want it to draw:

```
from turtle import *
import time
### Positioning
xpos= -250

ypos= -250

radius= 40

speed(10)

currentIterateCount = N

###Program main function
while currentIterateCount != 0:
    pu()
    goto (xpos, ypos)
    pd()
    begin_fill()
    color("red")
    circle(radius)
    end_fill()
    xpos = xpos + (radius*2)
    currentIterateCount--;
```

The reason that it drew more circles than you wanted is because you were checking against a variable that never changed.

By this I mean you were seeing if `radius` changed, but never changing it.

Comment: @HugoFanning - It can't possibly have worked. It doesn't even compile. (And that's apart from the suboptimal coding practice of keeping a manual loop counter in a language with easy iteration like Python.)

Answer (score 0):

`while radius == 40` - you never change `radius`, so it will never stop. Instead, loop over an iterable like `range()`:

```
for _ in range(5):
```

Remember, you don't *have* to use the loop variable within the loop. It's okay to use it as nothing other than a counter.